# Unpredictable behaviour when setting a boolean variable in JavaScript [Deep copying in strict mode]

Tags: javascript, boolean, windows-8.1, windows-store

```
function computerSetManapool(cost) {
    var splittedCost = cost.split(',');    
    for (var i = 0; i < splittedCost.length; i++) {                      
        if (splittedCost[i] === "CL") {
            for (var j = 0; j < computerLands.length; j++) {
                if (!computerLands[j].tapped) {
                    computerLands[j].tapped = true;
                    console.log(computerLands[j].name + " gets tapped");
                    break;
                }
            } 
        }
     }
}
```

I'm having a bit of trouble with this little piece of code, it's a Windows Store App, though I'm not using anything like the WinJS library or jQuery or what not. 
Especially this line worries me:

```
 computerLands[j].tapped = true;
```

I was debugging this in Visual Studio, while j had the value of 1. Therefore computerLands[1].tapped was supposed to be set to true.

Instead it set computerLands[1].tapped = true AND computerLands[3].tapped = true.
It does not happen every time, but many times and therefore I can't see what the problem is.

computerLands is an initially empty array, which then gets dynamically pushed objects into it.

If someone even has a remote idea what problem this could be, I would be really grateful.

Edit: This is the code where computerLands gets populated:

```
function computerTurn() {                                   
     untapAll("computer");
     drawCards(1, "computer");
     for (var i = 0; i < computerHand.length; i++) {             
          if (computerHand[i].type === "land") {
             var container = document.getElementById("computerLandsContainer");
             var newItem = document.createElement("div");                               
             newItem.id = computerLandsID;
             computerLandsID++;
             newItem.style.backgroundImage = "url("+computerHand[i].image+")";
             newItem.style.backgroundSize = "100%";
             var btn1 = document.createElement("button");
             btn1.id = "tapButtonComputer";                                              
             btn1.innerText = "˜";
             newItem.appendChild(createEnlargeButton(newItem,"computer"));
             newItem.appendChild(btn1);
             container.appendChild(newItem);
             computerLands.push(computerHand[i]);
             console.log("Computer plays: " + computerHand[i].name);
             computerLands[computerLands.length - 1].id = newItem.id;
             var index = computerHand.indexOf(computerHand[i]);
             computerHand.splice(index,1);
             break;
             }
      }
 }
```

The actual line is just this:

```
computerLands.push(computerHand[i]);
```

After pushing it into computerLands it gets removed from computerHand via splice().

```
var index = computerHand.indexOf(computerHand[i]);
computerHand.splice(index,1);
```

---

Finally I found a solution, I got it from this page: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/f79b2e68-15a9-4d5e-8aad-e15f78d94840/how-do-i-clone-an-object?forum=winappswithhtml5

It describes how to deep copy in Javascript in Windows Store Apps (this other solution I found http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/deep-copying-of-objects-and-arrays/ is not allowed in Windows Store Apps strict mode), basically you create a new object and copy every property into it. Now here's my new working code:

```
function populateComputerLands() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        //computerLands.push(availableComputerCards[0]);    <--- old code

        var objectToCopy = availableComputerCards[0];      // new code
        var newObject = Object.create(Object.getPrototypeOf(objectToCopy));
        var newObjectProperties = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(objectToCopy);
        var propertyName;
        for (var p in newObjectProperties) {
            propertyName = newObjectProperties[p];
            Object.defineProperty(newObject, propertyName, Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(objectToCopy, propertyName));
        };
        computerLands.push(newObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe `computerLands[1]` and `computerLands[3]` point to the same object? Posting the code that populates your array would allow us to tell for sure.

Comment: Are you making sure computerLands is empty before this function?

Comment: @Jono It is declared like this: var computerLands = []; and then I push(). How can I make sure it is empty and what would be the difference?

Comment: Surely `var index = computerHand.indexOf(computerHand[i]);` just results in `index === i` (unless an entry can be repeated)

Comment: @Alnitak Thanks for your comment, I probably chose a too complicated way. But still, my initial problem is when choosing one element from computerLands, it sometimes chooses several elements.

Comment: I think it has something to do with pointing to the same object, as stated in the first post, I will investigate more into that. Thanks so far.